# 2 session object java ee null exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm beginner with Java EE, when I try to transfer an object between a JSP and a Servlet I use a session.
For an homework, I have to create an e-commerce website.
I just have this in my jsp:

```
HttpSession sess = request.getSession();              
Panier pan = new Panier();
sess.setAttribute("panier", pan);
sess.setAttribute("produit", produits.get(0));
```

produits is an arraylist of "produit" object.

In my Servlet:

```
HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
Panier pan = (Panier) sess.getAttribute("panier");
Produit p1 = (Produit) sess.getAttribute("prod");
```

When I'm here, all works cause I can display the good attributes of the object pan or p1. But, when I use my method "ajouterProduit" (addProduct in English), a savage null pointer exception appears.

My class "Produit":

```
public class Produit implements java.io.Serializable{
private String nom;
private int prix;

public Produit(String name, int price){
    this.nom = name;
    this.prix = price;
}

public void setNom(String n){
    this.nom = n;
}

public void setPrix(int p){
    this.prix = p;
}

public String getNom(){
    return this.nom;
}

public int getPrix(){
    return this.prix;
}
}
```

My class "Panier" (basket in english):

```
public class Panier implements Serializable{
private List<Produit> panier;
private static int montant = 0;

public Panier(){
    panier = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void ajouterProduit(Produit p1){
    panier.add(p1);
    montant = montant + p1.getPrix();
}

public void ajouterProduit(Produit p1, Produit p2){
    panier.add(p1);
    montant = montant + p1.getPrix();
    panier.add(p2);
    montant = montant + p2.getPrix();
}

public void ajouterProduit(Produit p1, Produit p2,Produit p3){
    panier.add(p1);
    montant = montant + p1.getPrix();
    panier.add(p2);
    montant = montant + p2.getPrix();
    panier.add(p3);
    montant = montant + p3.getPrix();
}

public List<Produit> getPanier(){
    return panier;
}

public int getMontantTotal(){
    return montant;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for help ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add your "produit" like so:

```
sess.setAttribute("produit", produits.get(0));
```

But you retrieve it like so:

```
Produit p1 = (Produit) sess.getAttribute("prod");
```

`"prod"` and `"produit"` are 2 different session names. Your "produit" is not in `"prod"` session.

You store your product in the `produit` session, but you retrieve it from a `prod` session, which does not exist.

`p1` is, therefore, `null`.